# /usr/sbin/apache2: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/apache2: undefined symbol: apr_os_uuid_get

Tags: server, 18.04, permissions, apache2

I installed updates

On restart, apache2 yielded:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/apache2: undefined symbol: apr_os_uuid_get
```

I'm reinstalling the apache2 while I await the obvious quick-fix answer.

Already tried updating the library

`libaprutil1-dev is already the newest version (1.6.1-2ubuntu0.1)`

Comment: By "updates" do you mean that you upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 (or older) to something newer, and now Apache isn't working? This particular issue hasn't been an issue for most people for over five years 

Comment: i updated the linux libraries using apt-get update and it started happening

Comment: what can be a possible solution to this, since reinstalling apache2 hasnt helped

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of *actionable* data here. Is the 16.04 tag in your question accurate? If so, the only real solution is to upgrade your server to something newer. 16.04 has not been supported for almost two years ...

Comment: I upgraded it to 18.04 LTS moments ago, still the same.

Comment: You *may* be able to resolve it by installing the `libaprutil1-dev` package, however, I do not have any 16.04 or 18.04 systems available to test this 

Comment: `libaprutil1-dev is already the newest version (1.6.1-2ubuntu0.1)`

Comment: Please update the question with the new info and not in comments. The tag needs to be changed or this will still look like an old off topic 16.04 question.

Comment: Are you sure this is with an Ubuntu apache and not the Apache from the Apache website? "Already tried updating the library" updating is not what you want. You need the apr matching apache2 (or the apache2 matching apr).  To reset you need to purge apache, purge all apr related libs and then reinstall.

Comment: `ldd /usr/sbin/apache2` will show the version numbers,

Comment: Please don't forget that Ubuntu 18.04 LTS was released in 2018-April with 5 years of *standard* supported life, and its very rapidly approaching the end of that; so plan your *release-upgrade* to a supported system.  You're still on-topic with your question (*today & for a number of days yet*) but soon won't be.

Comment: AFAIK the symbol `apr_os_uuid_get` would be in libapr-1.so.0, which is provided by package libapr1 rather than libaprutil1-dev (which should only be required for *building* code, rather than simply running it)  so try `sudo apt install --reinstall libapr1`